# Lose session in websocket

Tags: websocket, aiohttp

i try to make chat, and when I make webSocket connection, I lose session data, where stored user auth token, therefore I cant check user authentication.
When I load page which contains form for webSocket connection, there are all session data.
I check many tutorials, but they don't have this kind of problem.

Thanks for your help!

My JS code here:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    url = window.location.href
    name = url.slice(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1)
    const chat = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:8080/chat/"+name);

    chat.onmessage = function(event) {
        data = JSON.parse(event.data)
        message = $('<div>', {class:'chat_message', text:`${data.message}`}).appendTo('.chat')
    };

    $('#chat_form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        if ($('.chat_form').find('textarea').val() == '') {
            return;
        }
        chat.send($('#chat_form').find('textarea').val())
    });

    })
```

My middleware:

```
@middleware
async def Auth(request, handler):
    request.session = session = await get_session(request)
    print(request.session)
    jwt_token = session.get('JWT', None)
    if jwt_token:
        user_credentials = jwt.decode(jwt_token, SECRET_KEY, algorithm='HS256')
        datetime_expires = datetime.datetime.strptime(user_credentials['expires'], '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M')
        if datetime_expires < datetime.datetime.now():
            await logout(request)
            request.user = UserInfo()
        else:
            async with request.app['db'].acquire() as conn:
                request.user = UserInfo(await conn.fetchrow('SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = $1', user_credentials['name']))
                await conn.close()
    else:
        request.user = UserInfo()
    resp = await handler(request)
    return resp
```

And my handler:

```
@routers_chat.view('/{user_name}')
class UserChat(web.View):

    async def broadcast(self, message):
        """
        Send message to all users of current chat
        """
        username = self.request.match_info['user_name']
        # Send fo all authorized peers
        for ws in self.request.app['user_web_sockets'][username]:
            response = dict(username=self.request.user.name, message=message)
            ws.send_json(response)
        # Send fo all unauthorized peers
        for ws in self.request.app['anon_web_sockets'][username]:
            print(ws)
            response = dict(username=self.request.user.name, message=message)
            ws.send_json(response)

    async def get(self):
        # Init WebSockets
        ws = web.WebSocketResponse()
        await ws.prepare(self.request)
        # Get owner of page name
        owner_username = self.request.match_info['user_name']
        # Check peer authentication
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            # Init user non anon webSocket
            owner_wsdict = self.request.app['chat']['user_web_sockets']
            # Collect webSocket
            if owner_username not in owner_wsdict:
                owner_wsdict[owner_username] = {self.request.user.name: ws}
            else:
                owner_wsdict[owner_username].update({self.request.user.name: ws})
            # Send message
            async for msg in ws:
                if msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.TEXT:
                    await self.broadcast(msg.data)
            # Close connection
            owner_wsdict[owner_username].pop(self.request.user.name)
            return ws
        else:
            # Init user anon webSocket
            owner_wsdict = self.request.app['chat']['anon_web_sockets']
            # Collect websocket
            if owner_username not in owner_wsdict:
                owner_wsdict[owner_username] = [ws]
            else:
                owner_wsdict[owner_username].append(ws)
            # Send error response
            async for msg in ws:
                if msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.TEXT:
                    response = dict(username='SERVER', message='You must be authorize!')
                    await ws.send_json(response)
            # Close connection
            owner_wsdict[owner_username].remove(ws)
            return ws
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay,I just installed nginx as proxy server, and all are just working now, and also I changed session storage from encrypted cookie to redis.